# How can I write an exact _itoa_s replacement with a modern C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, string, memory, char, buffer

I've come across an old piece of code that I need to get working, but I can't compile it because my compiler doesn't recognize the _itoa_s function. I don't know much about the low level capabilities of old fashioned programming, and I don't entirely understand the workings of functions like _itoa_s, so this is a road block for me.

Is there any way I can create an exact equivalent of the following code that works with normal C++ standards?

```
char buff[80896]; // = 1024 * 79
char len[255];
_itoa_s(length, len, 10);
// Btw, the "length" variable is the length of a string provided by user input
```

Also, what exactly does this do? It's a part of some voodoo that's over my head. It's one of the steps in a chunk of code that's designed to successfully call a function inside another process that isn't supposed to be called, so if it's doing something strange, it's pretty important that the alternative does exactly the same thing.

Comment: It converts an integer to its ASCII representation. You could use `sprintf(len, "%.*s", 10, length)` if you're not too concerned about performance.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, I'll try that out.

Comment: You also have the http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/ to_string variants.